# new SafeApiKit returning "TypeError: SafeApiKit is not a constructor"

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have followed the guides from the documentation:

- https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/protocol-kit
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/guides/integrating-the-safe-core-sdk.md

But when trying to initialize the API Kit I'm getting the error "TypeError: SafeApiKit is not a constructor".

1. Initialize Signers, Providers and EthAdapter
   [image]

The ethAdapterOwner1 has data inside, is initialized correctly.

2. Initialize the API Kit
   [image]

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by destructuring the `default` from `SafeApiKit` like this:

```js
  const safeService = new SafeApiKit.default({
    txServiceUrl,
    ethAdapter: ethAdapterOwner1,
  });
```